# Case Statement T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

Everything was working fine with the script below until I tried to add a Case Statement with a SELECT Clause I had done this to auto populate the table with the correct dates can some let me know what have I done wrong?

```
DECLARE @PitchType_Skey INT
DECLARE @Site_Skey INT
DECLARE @Capacity INT
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE

SET @PitchType_Skey = 1
SET @Site_Skey = 1
SET @Capacity = 0

WHILE (@Site_Skey < 127)

BEGIN
    IF @PitchType_Skey = 8

BEGIN

SET @PitchType_Skey = 1
SET @Site_Skey = @Site_Skey + 1

END

IF (@Site_Skey < 127)

BEGIN

Set @Capacity = (SELECT SiteWeighting From Site Where Site_Skey = @Site_Skey)
Set @Capacity = @Capacity * (SELECT PitchTypeWeighting From PitchType  Where PitchType_Skey = @PitchType_Skey)
Set @Capacity = @Capacity * ((10*(100+((RAND()*40)-20)))*0.01)

     INSERT INTO Capacity 
     SELECT
     CASE @StartDate
     WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE SiteWeighting = 1 THEN 01/05/2010) ELSE,
     WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE SiteWeighting = 2 THEN 01/04/2010) ELSE,
     WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE SiteWeighting = 3 THEN 01/04/2010) ELSE,
     WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE SiteWeighting = 4 THEN 01/01/2010) ELSE,

     CASE @EndDate
     WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE SiteWeighting = 1 THEN 30/09/2010) ELSE,
     WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE SiteWeighting = 2 THEN 01/11/2010) ELSE,
     WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE SiteWeighting = 3 THEN 01/11/2010) ELSE,
     WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE SiteWeighting = 4 THEN 01/12/2010) ELSE,

      round(@Capacity,0) as Capacity,
      @PitchType_Skey, @Site_Skey

END
  SET @PitchType_Skey = @PitchType_Skey + 1

END
```

Comment: Note: in SQL, `IF` is a statement, but `CASE` is an expression/function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have your parentheses in the wrong place.  `THEN` is part of the case statement, but you have it inside the subquery. You also only want one `ELSE` per case statement.

It's hard to know if there are more mistakes without knowing more about your table, but a syntactically correct case statement would look something like this:

```
CASE @StartDate
  WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_SKey=@Site_SKey)=1 THEN '01/05/2010'
  WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_SKey=@Site_SKey)=2 THEN '01/04/2010'
  ELSE NULL 
END
```

However, I strongly suggest that you don't use a case statement for this.  Instead, use something else, like a lookup table with start and end dates that you can join based on `SiteWeighting`.  It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Hi Dan, I am learning and I have been told to use a Case Statement so if I move the parentheses to the end of the =1 would this solve the issue?

Comment: @wafw1971, see the update for an example of a case statement.  You might need to update your question with more info on the table structure and what you are trying to do, though.  I'm not sure exactly what is needed.

Comment: I have a Site Table that has a Site Weighting Column, each Site is weighted between 1 and 4, I am currently working on the Capacity table and want to use the weighting from the Site Table to determine the Start and End Date.

Comment: I have tried your changes but I still cant upload then into the Capacity Table.

Comment: @wafw1971, I think I see what you are doing.  Try the updated version.  The key is that you want to make sure you get the record matching the current site from the Site table.

Comment: Hi Dan

Thanks for your help, with it I came up with the following result which worked great:

SELECT
       CASE
       WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey)=1 THEN '1 May 2010'
       WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey)=2 THEN '1 Apr 2010' WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey)=3 THEN '1 Apr 2010'
WHEN (SELECT SiteWeighting FROM Site WHERE Site_Skey=@Site_Skey)=4 THEN '1 Jan 2010'
       ELSE NULL
       END as StartDate,